# A metric defined on the space of all positive finite measures.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb M$ be the space of all positive finite measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{M})$.

$$(\lambda,\nu) \mapsto d(\lambda,\nu) \equiv 2\sup_{E \in \mathcal M} |\lambda(E) - \nu(E)|$$ is a metric on this space.

Suppose $\mu \geq \lambda$, $\mu \geq \nu$, $\lambda(X) = \nu(X)=1$.

***We must show that $$d(\lambda,\nu) = \int |\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu} - \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}| \,d\mu = 2\left ( 1 - \int (\min (\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}(x),\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x))) \,d\mu\right)$$***

**My attempt:**

For each measurable $E$, $$\lambda(E) - \nu(E) = 1 - \lambda(E^c) - (1 - \nu(E^c)) = \nu(E^c) - \lambda(E^c)$$

This implies that $$d(\lambda,\nu) = \sup_{E \in \mathcal{M}} (\lambda(E) - \nu(E)) + \sup_{E \in \mathcal{M}} (\nu(E) - \lambda(E)) = \int_{(\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}\geq \frac{d\nu}{d\mu})} |\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu} - \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}| \,d\mu+ \int_{(\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}< \frac{d\nu}{d\mu})} |\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu} - \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}| \,d\mu = \int |\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu} - \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}| \,d\mu$$.

This proves the first equality.  As for the second, what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the set on which $d\lambda / d \mu \leq d\nu / d\mu$. Then

$$\int \min \left ( \frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}, \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \right ) \, d\mu = \lambda(A) + \nu(A^c) = \lambda (A) - \nu(A) + 1$$
and apparently the claim is
$$d(\lambda, \mu) = 2(\nu(A) - \lambda(A))$$
which you proved to be true as it follows from
$$\sup \{|\nu(E) - \lambda(E)|\} = \sup \{\nu(E) - \lambda(E)\} = \nu(A) - \lambda(A)$$